# How to convert letters in string to numbers - C++

Tags: c++

I'm kinda a newbie to c++...had the class for about a month or so... Anywho, we are doing this final project where we have to make an encryption/ decryption program using the hill cipher method. I've run into a slight problem where when I am trying to return the numbers from the function, it displays symbols instead of the actual numbers. The function itself, however, works correctly. Even though this is homework/classwork, the teacher is allowing us to use online sources and external help, since, as I previously said, we have only been programming for a month or so. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
 #define NOMINMAX
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int random1()
{
    unsigned long long int xRan;
    srand(time(NULL));
again:
    xRan = rand() * 319 / 43 * 16 * 333 % 9999 + 1;
    if (xRan <= 0)
        goto again;
    return xRan;
}
int random2()
{
    unsigned long long int xRan;
    srand(time(NULL));
again:
    xRan = rand() * 319 * 43 / 16 * 321 % 9999 + 1;
    if (xRan <= 0)
        goto again;
    return xRan;
}
int random3()
{
    unsigned long long int xRan;
    srand(time(NULL));
again:
    xRan = rand() * 319 / 43 / 16 * 2 % 9999 + 1;
    if (xRan <= 0)
        goto again;
    return xRan;
}

int convert(char conv)
{
    return (int)conv-87;
}

int matrixMult(double q, double w, double e)
{
    int i, j, k, count = 0, total = 0;

    double a, s, z, x, c, v, b, n, m;

    a = random1();
    s = random2();
    z = random3();
    x = random1();
    c = random2();
    v = random3();
    b = random1();
    n = random2();
    m = random3();

    int A[1][3] = { q, w, e };

    int B[3][3] = {
        { a, s, z },
        { x, c, v },
        { b, n, m }
    };

    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
                total += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            cout << setw(5) << total << ' ';
            ++count;
            if (count % 3 == 0)
                cout << endl;
            total = 0;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    string again = "y";

    cout << "Would you like to encrypt or decrypt?(e/d) " << endl;
    string ende;
    cin >> ende;



    if (ende == "e")
    {
        cout << "Please enter a name for the message: " << endl;
        string file;
        cin >> file;

        file += ".txt";
        ofstream encrypt;
        encrypt.open(file);


        string message;
        cout << "Please enter the message you would like to encrypt: " << endl << endl;
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        getline(cin, message);

        //int length = message.size();

        char converted[9999];

        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); ++i)
        {
            converted[i] = convert(message[i]);
            cout << converted[i] << endl;
        }





        encrypt.close();

        cout << "Your message has been encrypted.\nPlease check " << file << " for the encrypted message and key" << endl;
    }
    if (ende == "d")
    {
        cout << "0";

    }






    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just `int converted[9999];`. You declared it as char, so it prints characters

Comment: those gotos can be replaced by do-while loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int converted[9999];
for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); ++i){
    converted[i] = convert(message[i]);
    cout << converted[i] << endl;
}
```

You've declared `converted` as `char` while you need to print out numbers. You'd better declare it as `int` or use `cout << int(converted[i]) << endl;`

By the way, using `endl` can make the program be a bit slow. You can use `"\n"` instead.

Comment: The only time you need `endl` is just before you ask for input.

Comment: @MarkRansom and often not even then... the input and output streams are _tied_, meaning that an input operation will first flush the output buffer. See e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie